# Counting date and time with SUMPRODUCT or COUNTIF(S) based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to produce a sheet whereby the number of times a name appears on a given date.

The issue I am coming up against is that the date and time source is not able to be adjusted.

For example the source data is displayed as "08/09/2014 17:34" but I do not need the time part of this.

Logically the required SUMPRODUCT would be as below. Where A1 being the date and A14 being the persons name.

```
SUMPRODUCT((DATEVALUE(Data!D:D)=A1)*(Data!B:B=A14))
```

But this displays as #VALUE.

I can convert the date and time cell to a format that works by using, (D1 being an example of date format shown above)

```
DATEVALUE(YEAR(D1)&"/"& MONTH(D1)&"/"& DAY(D1))
```

But then I do not know if this is possible to implement into a SUMPRODUCT formula.

I have also tried with TEXT and LEFT but these do not show in a format that allows the dates to be matched.

I am trying to do this all with formulas, but if need be I can also use VBA.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If A1 contains e.g. 08/09/2014 17:34:00 then =INT(A1) will return 08/09/2014. Perhaps you can incorporate this into your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following setup -

> `A                      B 
>   17/09/2014 15:51    Joe Bloggs
>   13/09/2014 15:51    Joe Bloggs
>   12/09/2014 15:51    Joe Bloggs
>   08/09/2014 15:51    Joe Bloggs
>   08/09/2014 15:51    Joe Bloggs
>   15/09/2014 15:51    Joe Bloggs
>   10/09/2014 15:51    Joe Bloggs
>   14/09/2014 15:51    Joe Bloggs
>   11/09/2014 15:51    Joe Bloggs
>   10/09/2014 15:51    Joe Bloggs`
>   
>   
>       `D 
>   Joe Bloggs
>   08/09/2014`

The formula below will find the correct number of times the two criteria in **column D** are satisfied, regardless of timestamp:

`{=SUM((B1:B10=D1)*(DATE(YEAR(A1:A10),MONTH(A1:A10),DAY(A1:A10))=$D$2))}`

Leave out the curly braces and enter the formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

The feature you want to use is [Pivot Tables](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-report-HP010089893.aspx#_Toc263767342). It's really easy to do exactly what you want with just a few clicks once you learn how to use that feature.

Comment: I did think about that one too, but hit the same problem with the dates, if I adjust the format in the pivot I end up with hundreds of the same date. I am not sure if or how I can adjust so that each date only appears once.